# LaTeX renders my figures on each other

Tags: graphics

I have the following header defined:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn,letterpaper]{article}
```

I then add two figures in different places.

The first one - is "page-wide" and is set with `[width=\textwidth]`

The next one, which is defined two subsections later, is "column-wide" and is set with `[width=\linewidth]`.

When the PDF paper is created, the first figure is shown as expected, it starts where the first column starts and ends where the second column ends.

The problem is, that when the second one is rendered, as expected, within one of the columns, it is overlapping with the first one and hides almost a half of it.

Is there a way to prevent it?

This is an example for how I created the first figure:

```
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{training_main_flow.png}
  \caption{Lalala Lilili}
  \label{fig:TrainingMainFlow}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Did you try `figure*` instead of `figure`?

Comment: No. Shall I simply add a trailing `*` after the `figure` keyword? I am quite new to LaTeX..

Comment: Only if you are in `twocolumn` mode and want to use a figure that spans over both columns.

Comment: Yes, I've just noticed that when turning the one-column figures into `figure*`, it ignores my width settings. Changing only the wide one to `figure*` seems to do the work. Thanks!

Comment: it does not _ignore_ your width settings it follows them exactly. You are in a single column but you have specified that the image be scaled to `\textwidth` (which is what it does, even though it does not fit and will overprint the next column or the right hand margin)